# How to disable http traffic and force https with kubernetes ingress on gcloud

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi i tried the new annotation for ingress explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001557/how-to-force-ssl-for-kubernetes-ingress-on-gke)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ssl-iagree-ingress
  annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.allowHTTP: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: secret-cert-myown
  backend:
    serviceName: modcluster
    servicePort: 80
```

but i can still access it trough http, this is my setup on gcloud **ingress**--**apache:80**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well i was able to resolve the issue, thanks to Mr Danny, from this pull request [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/pull/1462), there was a typo in

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allowHTTP: "false"
```

change it to

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

and it works fine now.

ps: only for master version 1.3.5

Comment: I tried this approach as well, but I noticed that traffic on `http` was **not redirected** to `https`. It just didn't allow any traffic on `http`. Is there a way to *force* `https`?

Comment: To redirect traffic you have to do it trough apache