# HTTP to HTTPS redirect in backend behind GCLB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

To my knowledge Google Cloud Load Balancer is not supporting HTTP to HTTPS redirect out of the box and it's a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733

Currently, I'm sending certain requests to GKE backend where I run Kubernetes apps and I have GCS-backed backends. I'm also using Apache in the default backend where I force HTTPS.

Problem with this approach is that, if any request match the criteria for GKE backend, I have no way to force HTTPS. I'm thinking to use Apache backend for all requests (?) and somehow proxy some of them to GKE backend. This way Apache backend becomes a bottleneck and I'm not sure if it's a good solution at all.

How would you approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the only way is to send HTTP traffic to custom backend (it can be apache/nginx) and force the HTTPS upgrade there.

I find this answer useful if you're using GKE backend with an Ingress.

[How to force SSL for Kubernetes Ingress on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001557/how-to-force-ssl-for-kubernetes-ingress-on-gke)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks @GregtheIncredulous for the useful advice!

Comment: this is implemented now: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management

Answer (score -1):

To force SSL traffic from Load Balancer to GKE backend (pod), you need to expose port 443 (or similar) on the pod and configure SSL there.