# GKE ingress answers in HTTP even my service uses HTTPS only

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have Nginx-based service which configured to accept HTTPS-only. 
However GKE ingress answers HTTP requests in HTTP. I know that GKE Ingress doesn't know to enforce HTTP -> HTTPS redirect, but is it possible to learn it at least return HTTPS from service?

```
rules:
  - http:
  paths:
  - path: /*
    backend:
      serviceName: dashboard-ui
      servicePort: 8443
```

UPDATE: I do have TSL configured on GKE ingress and my K8S service. When request comes in HTTPS everything works nice. But HTTP requests gets HTTP response. I implemented HTTP->HTTPS redirect in my service, but it didn't help. In fact, for now all communication between ingress and my service is HTTTPS because service exposes only HTTPS port

SOLUTION - thanks to Paul Annetts:  Nginx should check original protocol inside *HTTPS* block and redirect, like this

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Hi nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS" https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#backend-protocol this Annotation might be helpful

Comment: Suresh, I use GKE ingress, not Nginx-based

Comment: There will be a similar annotation, as these functionalities are enabled using annotations. I will look into GKE Ingress

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'm not sure that "backend-protocol" is relevant for my issue. My "dashboard-ui" listens on 8080 (http) and 8443 (https), with HTTP->HTTPS redirect. As you can see in my ingress config, it uses only HTTPS service port for access my service.

Comment: Hi @Vitaly I'm having same issue as you but not sure how to set that configuration, would you mind to share your configuration please?

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
             return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
          }`

Comment: @user2669657, I used almost the same config: under HTTP nginx server I have

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }

It's not nginx ingres, just 'my' nginx in frontend of my services.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure the GKE Kubernetes Ingress to both terminate HTTPS for external traffic, and also to use HTTPS internally between Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer and your service inside the GKE cluster.

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress), but it is fairly complex.

For HTTPS to work you will need a TLS certificate and key.

If you have your own TLS certificate and key in the cluster as a secret, you can provide it using the `tls` section of `Ingress`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-2
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-metrics
          servicePort: 60000
```

You can also upload your TLS certificate and key directly to Google Cloud and provide a `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert` annotation that tells GKE Ingress to use it.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-psc-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "my-domain-tls-cert"
...
```

To use HTTPS for traffic inside Google Cloud, from the Load Balancer to your GKE cluster, you need the `cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"my-https-port":"HTTPS","my-http-port":"HTTP"}'` annotation on your `NodePort` service. Note that your ports must be named for the HTTPS to work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service-3
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"my-https-port":"HTTPS","my-http-port":"HTTP"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: metrics
    department: sales
  ports:
  - name: my-https-port
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: my-http-port
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001
```

The load balancer itself doesn’t support redirection from HTTP->HTTPS, you need to find another way for that.

As you have NGINX as entry-point into your cluster, you can detect the protocol used to connect to the load-balancer with the `X-forwarded-Proto` HTTP header and do a redirect, something like this.

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Paul, thank you! I guess I didn't explain myself well:

I do have TSL configured on GKE ingress and my K8S service. When request comes in HTTPS everything works nice. But HTTP requests gets HTTP response. I implemented HTTP->HTTPS redirect in my service, but it didn't help. In fact, for now *all* communication between ingress and my service is HTTTPS because service exposes only HTTPS  port.

Comment: Yeah, so the Load Balancer and Ingress on GKE itself doesn’t support HTTP->HTTPS redirect (yet?). That’s something you need to do in your service. Luckily it looks like you have NGINX as your entry point, you can get that to do the redirect quite easily.

Comment: I’ve added a snippet of NGINX redirect you can use into the answer.

Comment: Another alternative is to consider NGINX ingress controller as per this answer on a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923210/694641.

Comment: Paul, many thanks!
Checking http_x_forwarded_proto  inside *https*  block fixed my issue

Comment: Yes, that makes sense if the traffic is over HTTPS from the LB.

Comment: There is now an option to redirect http to https. in FrontendConfig:   `redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: PERMANENT_REDIRECT`